# xmlhttp.Open "GET" - Getting the URL from the db classic asp and 2008r2

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have a clasic asp VB script gets data from an MS-SQL server 2008r2 db and then puts the sting in a URL so that xmlhttp can get some data.

When I store the whole URL in the db, this fails (I can display the url via Response.Write so it looks like it gets to the page) but if I just store a part of the URL (a number) it works.

I want to be able to store the whole url in the form `"http://xxx.xxx.co.uk/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.xxx"`

After a bit of fiddling about, its looking like it may be to do with the forward slashes in the URL.  I have set the page to charset=utf-8 which normally seems to work with most out put but this doesn't seem to make any difference if its included or not.

Can anybody shed any light on this as its starting to confuse me.

Why can does this work:

In db scpw is stored as: 123456 (nchar)

```
strSQL_cal_list = "SELECT scpw FROM tbl"
Set rsSQL_cal_list = conn.Execute(strSQL_cal_list) 

While Not rsSQL_cal_list.EOF
sclogin = Trim(rsSQL_cal_list("scpw"))

dim strUrl : strUrl = "http://xxx.xxx.co.uk/xxx/xxx/xxx/"&sclogin&"/xxx.xxx"

xmlhttp.setTimeouts lResolve, lConnect, lSend, lReceive
xmlhttp.Open "GET", strUrl, false 
xmlhttp.Send ""
```

and this not work:

In db scpw is stored as: `http://xxx.xxx.co.uk/xxx/xxx/xxx/123456/xxx.xxx` (nchar)

```
strSQL_cal_list = "SELECT scpw FROM tbl"
Set rsSQL_cal_list = conn.Execute(strSQL_cal_list) 

While Not rsSQL_cal_list.EOF
sclogin = Trim(rsSQL_cal_list("scpw"))

dim strUrl : strUrl = sclogin
xmlhttp.setTimeouts lResolve, lConnect, lSend, lReceive
xmlhttp.Open "GET", strUrl, false 
xmlhttp.Send ""
```

Edit - this works although not sure why

In db scpw is stored as: `http://xxx.xxx.co.uk/xxx/xxx/xxx/123456/xxx.xxx` (nchar)

```
strSQL_cal_list = "SELECT scpw FROM tbl"
Set rsSQL_cal_list = conn.Execute(strSQL_cal_list) 

While Not rsSQL_cal_list.EOF
sclogin = Trim(rsSQL_cal_list("scpw"))

xmlhttp.setTimeouts lResolve, lConnect, lSend, lReceive
xmlhttp.Open "GET", sclogin, false 
xmlhttp.Send ""
```

Comment: If this is about configuring a classic asp page to use UTF-8 then you should read this blog - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: what is the error message?